# How to pass command-line arguments to a python script from within another script?

Tags: python, command-line

I've got a python script that is named `code.py` and this takes two command line arguments `--par_value xx --out_dir /path/to/dir` where `par_value` is a certain parameter and `out_dir` is the output directory. I want to run this script for different values of the input parameter.

So I want to use the array:

```
par_vector = np.array([1,2,3])
```

and have the output file for each named, say, "output_1", "output_2" and "output_3". So I'm trying to write a python script where I can create that array above and an array of output strings, say, called `output_strings` so I can automatically run something along the like:

```
for i,j in zip(par_vector, output_strings): 
 python code.py --par_value i --out_dir j
```

But this does not run so I'm unable to figure out how to make such an automation of my code work rather than repeatedly calling the script `code.py` from the terminal. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: look into the subprocess library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: Why don't you just import and directly call the relevant functionality?

Comment: @ajoseps        That did the job! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit convoluted, but *a* way you could do it is to generate either `.bat` or `.sh` files (depending on your operating system) and call them with `Popen` from the `subprocess` library.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for i,j in zip(par_vector, output_strings): 
    cmd = """python code.py --par_value {} --out_dir {}""".format(i,j)
    temp_filename = "{}{}.bat".format(i,) #swap .bat for .sh if not on Windows
    
    with open(temp_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(cmd)
    
    execution = Popen([temp_filename], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    results = execution.communicate()
    
    # add conditions based on the output generated by results if you want to use it to verify, etc.

    os.remove(temp_filename)
```

Obviously this needs to be changed to match your exact needs for the file name and location, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would use `os.system` for this if you're OK with the fact that `os.system()` is blocking. This would look something like:

```
import os    
for i,j in zip(par_vector, output_strings): 
    os.system(f"python code.py --par_value {i} --out_dir {j}")
```